# How to combine different feature values to build a score for ranking

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, information-theory

I am doing some information extraction study on some data. We extract a "word" list from the data. And for each "word", it has a n dimensional feature vector in R ^n. Next, We want to rank the list according to a score. The question is, how can I combine all the feature values to build a score function for my ranking. The difficulty is we can only work in an unsupervised way. I think many people are facing to this question in bioinformatic or other area when doing IE, right? I had thought about max entropy, but it usually works in supervised way. Is there any good method to solve this problem in unsupervised way ?

Comment: Ask yourself (and tell us ?): What is the desired property of the ranking ? Without a metric, any ranking is fine.

Comment: Are all the n features equally important?  And, as @steffen asks, what is the point of the ranking?  Is it to get the "best" words on the top of the list (in which case, are the measurements of the n features all such that bigger is better)?  Or perhaps just to get similar words as close as possible to eachother in the list?  If the former, then a simple weighted average of the features would work.  If the latter (you want similarity), some variant of multidimensional scaling might do the trick.